# Prove that the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}X_n$ converges almost surely

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables

> Let $(X_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence of real valued random variables defined on some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A},P)$. Assume that there exists a sequence of real numbers $(a_n)_{n\ge 0}$ such that both series 
>   $$\sum_{n\ge 0}a_n \quad and \quad\sum_{n\ge 0}P(X_n\neq a_n)$$
>   converge. Prove that the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}X_n$ converges almost surely.

I don't really know how to solve this problem. The first thing that I don't understand is the sentence

> Prove that the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}X_n$ converges almost surely.

What is the series intended to converge to? I've thought it is intended to converge almost surely to $0$, so that the statement to prove would be
$$P\left(\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}X_n =0 \right)=1$$

But then i can't really move on. I was thinking to use Strong Law of Large Numbers, but to use it the sequence of random variables must be i.i.d. and in the *Problem* they are not. Do you have any hint?

Comment: If you have almost sure convergence then $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}X_n$ is a random variable which is finite with probability $1$.  As an example, if all the $a_n=0$ and  $P(X_n=2^n)=\frac{1}{2^{2^n}+1}$ while $P(X_n=0)=\frac{2^{2^n}}{2^{2^n}+1}$ independently for $n\ge 0$, then $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}X_n$ converges to a geometric random variable with  $P\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}X_n =k\right) = 2^{-k}$: it can take any non-negative integer value and the probabilities of taking one of these sum to $1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By "the series $\sum\limits_n X_n$ converge almost surely", it is meant that there exists $\Omega'$ of probability $1$ for which if $\omega\in\Omega'$, then 
the series of real numbers $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}X_n(\omega)$ is convergent.

Define the event $E_n:=\{X_n\neq a_n\}$. We get by the assumption that $\mathbb P\left(\limsup\limits_nE_n\right)=0$. Can you show that if $\omega$ belongs to the complement of $\limsup\limits_nE_n$, then the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}X_n(\omega)$ is convergent?

Comment: +1! Thank you for your help!

I'm trying to follow your hint. What I've understood so far is that by Borel Cantelly and the assumption that $\sum_n P(X_n \neq a_n) < \infty$ follows that $\mathbb P\left(\limsup\limits_nE_n\right)=0$. From this i can understand that there are only *finite* many $\omega \in \Omega$ such that $X_n(\omega) \neq a_n$. (is it correct?). This means that there are *infinitely* many $\omega \in \Omega$ in the complement of $E_n$. Now if we pick $\Omega' := E_n^c$ we have an event of probability $1$ right? I think that this would imply that the series

Comment: $\sum_{n} X_n$ converges, but i'm not sure why...

Comment: More exactly, there is $\Omega'$ of probability $1$ for which if $\omega\in \Omega'$ then $\omega\notin\limsup_n E_n$. ($E_n$ is not necessarily of probability $1$: its probability goes to $0$ after all). If $\omega\notin \limsup_n E_n$, this means that for some $N$ depending of $\omega$, we have $\omega\notin E_n$ if $n\geqslant N$. If you change finitely many terms of a series, its convergence/divergence won't change.

Comment: Sorry, i've meant to pick $\Omega' = E_n^c$.

Ok, so summarizing: $P(\limsup E_n=0)$ implies that there exists $N(\omega)$ such that $\forall n > N(\omega)$, $\omega \notin E_n$. Since the event $E_n$ is the event of all $\omega$ such that $X_n(\omega) \neq a_n$ and since we have shown that this event has probability $0$, this means that there exists a set $\Omega'$ such that for all $\omega \in \Omega'$ $X_n(\omega) = a_n$ and since the series $\sum_{n}a_n$ converges we have that $\sum_{n} X_n(\omega)$ converges for all $\omega$ in that set right?

Comment: Thank you very very much! Have a nice evening!