# Show that $\sum_n P(X_n>M) <\infty$ implies $P(\sup_n X_n <\infty)=1$

Tags: probability-theory

> Show that $\sum_n P(X_n>M) <\infty$, for some M, implies $P(\sup_n X_n
>  <\infty)=1$.

**What I did.**

By Borel-Cantelli $\sum_n P(X_n>M) <\infty$ implies that  $P(\limsup_n \{X_n>M\})=0$.

Since, $\inf_n \{X_n>M\} \subset \limsup_n \{X_n>M\}$ then $0=P(\limsup_n \{X_n>M\}) \ge P(\inf_n \{X_n>M\})\ge 0$. So, $P(\inf_n \{X_n>M\})=0$.

Now $0=P(\inf_n \{X_n>M\})=1-P(\sup_n \{X_n<M\})$ then $P(\sup_n \{X_n<M\})=1$.
Which implies that $P( \{\sup_n X_n<M\})=1$ (is this switch correct?) for some M.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: If you take $X_n=\frac{1}{n-1}$. $P(X_n>M)=1$ for $n=1$ and $0$ for $n>1$ and any $M>1$.

Comment: @d.k.o. Are you showing an example? I don't understand what is your point?

Comment: The point is that $\sup_n X_n=X_1=\infty$ a.s. (in this example)

Comment: In addition, $\inf_n \{X_n>M\}$ and $\limsup_n \{X_n>M\}$ are sets. So, what does $\inf_n \{X_n>M\} \le \limsup_n \{X_n>M\}$ mean?

Comment: corrected. Now use subset notation.

Comment: @d.k.o. My friend are you trying to say that my proof is wrong? I still trying to understand what you mean.

Comment: Probably, my example is not good if $X_n$'s are finite...

Comment: Generally, $P(X_n>M\text{ i.o.})=0$ implies that $\limsup X_n\le M<\infty$ a.s. which implies that $\sup X_n\le \infty$ a.s.

Comment: Ok. This I agree with.

Comment: I think [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/905205/prove-that-the-series-sum-limits-n-0-inftyx-n-converges-almost-surely) can help you :)